# Webpack output bundle larger than expected

Tags: javascript, webpack

The only thing I have in my entry JS file is:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

The jQuery JS file has the size of **29.5kb** from [jsdelivr](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js).
My entry, that only includes jQuery, and nothing else, has the size of **86kb**.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/scripts.js',
    output: {
        publicPath: "./dist/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/js/"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        ['env', { loose:true, modules:false }],
                        'stage-2'
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        ['transform-react-jsx', { pragma:'h' }]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                use: [
                    "file-loader?name=[name].html&outputPath=../dist",
                    "extract-loader",
                    "html-loader",
                    "pug-html-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: ['css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "TweenMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js'),
            "TimelineMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax.js'),
            "animation.gsap": path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js'),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/main.css'),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            test: /\.js($|\?)/i
        })
    ],
    stats: {
        warnings: false
    }
};
```

I should also mention, that going into the output **bundle.js** it still has the jQuery comments.

> jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1
>    https://jquery.com/ ...

Even though I'm calling webpack with the `-p` argument and have the UglifyJS plugin, but the rest of the file is minified and mangled. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: To elaborate slightly on @niyoko-yuliawan's answer: Most web browsers support some form of compression. In the response headers when I accessed your jquery link above, it showed `content-encoding: br`, meaning it was compressed with the Brotli algorithm. Size 84.9KB, transferred (compressed size) 29.6KB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to copy and paste minified jquery from your link. It's has size of **86.9 kb**.
[This link](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/jquery-size) also show that jquery v3 minified file size is also around **80kb**.

So you already have correct setup. Maybe your **29.5kb** file size is **minified+gzipped** file.

Answer (score 0):

The 29.5kb file size is definitely the minified+gzipped version as per the link Niyoko posted.

I would also recommend checking out [Fuse-Box](https://fuse-box.org/) It brought down our project size from over 1mb to under 200kb (Vendor and App bundles combined). Very easy to get going as well and it is TypeScript first :) It takes the best features from a number of the more popular bundlers and brings them together and builds on those features.